# Как отключить небольшое затемнение в верхней части NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Я так понимаю это затемнение предназначено для верхнего статус бара, но я использую отступ от него, поэтому мне это затемнение нужно убрать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите разметку

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570265/3212712) так убрать тень:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```